# popup in my chrome-extension is not executing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently learning the basics of chrome-extension. popup.html is not poppping...

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Lemufied!!!!!!!!!!",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "background"],
  "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["http://*/*"],"js": ["inject.js"]}],
  "browser_action": {"default_icon": "16x16.png","popup": "popup.html"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a version 2 manifest, you should define the **[browser-action popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest)** like this:

```
"browser_action": {
    ...
    "default_popup": ...
```